# Joining tables preserving order with possible multiple occurrences

Tags: sql, join

I have table A ordered by ord1:

```
_______________
| ord1 | col1 | 
---------------
| 1    |  abc |
---------------
| 2    |  def |
---------------
| 3    |  ghi |
---------------
| 4    |  abc |
--------------- 
| 5    |  jkl |
---------------
| 6    |  def |
---------------
| 7    |  mno |
---------------
```

... and table B, ordered by ord2:

```
_______________
| ord2 | col2 | 
---------------
| 1    |  abc |
---------------
| 2    |  ghi |
---------------
| 3    |  pqr |
---------------
| 4    |  abc |
---------------
```

I need to join table A with table B in a preserving ordered way to obtain:

```
___________________
| ord1| ord2| col1|
-------------------
| 1   | 1   | abc |
------------------- 
| 3   | 2   | ghi |
------------------- 
| 4   | 4   | abc |
-------------------
```

So, I need to join over col1 and col2 but Table B must act as a "filter" for Table A.
Note the multiple occurrences in Table A and Table B.

Regards,
Antonio

Comment: What would happen if row 7 in table 1 were "ghi" and row 3 was something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT t1.ord1,MAX(t2.ord2)ord2,t1.col1
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.col1=t2.col2
AND  t1.ord1>=t2.ord2
GROUP BY t1.ord1
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fedcb4/15)

Comment: Why do you compare ord1 and ord2? In table B ord2 could be 500,600,700,800 instead of 1,2,3,4.

Comment: Dbms should not be a matter, however it is Oracle.